# Using .load() function

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load some image from the anchor tag.

```
<a href="localhost\system\uploads\Lead\test.jpg" class="image"></a>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

The image is loaded in another page rather than on the div that i specified.
Here's the code that i am using:

```
$(document).on("click",".image", function (e) {
      $("#preview").load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Am i doing something wrong?Please suggest me some solutions.Thanks.

Comment: `a` is a link, ,`<img` is for images.. come on man use google

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Do you mean i cannot use load function on anchor tags?
cause i believe src is only for the images?

Comment: @jycr753 i know..i was just confused using the load function.

Comment: @jycr753 Can't I have link for images? Why should i google that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
$(document).on("click",".image", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="'+ href  +'" />');
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on("click",".image", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#preview").html($("<img />").attr("src", this.href));
});
```

Comment: Thanks..but the result is same as before.

Comment: Your example works :) Just had to use preventDefault() function to stop the previous result :D

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi Ok, added :D. Btw `e.preventDefault();` used to prevent the default action of your anchor which is moving to the `href` on click

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you feel satisfied?